# Converting datetime to days; minutes and hours in sql

Tags: sql-server, casting, timestamp

I am trying to convert the date difference between a column `datatime` and `current_timestamp` in `Microsoft SQL Server`

Below is an example of the coding and output I am getting:

**code**

```
select top 1
    [Date & Time] = '2021-02-18 20:45:49.0000000' 
    ,convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(dd,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) + 'Days'
    + convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(HH,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) % 24) + 'Hours' 
    + convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MI,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) % 60) + 'Mins' as [Waiting Time]
from Invoices
```

**current output**

```
 Date & Time                |     Waiting Time
2021-02-18 20:45:49.0000000 |   1Days15Hours0Mins
```

**expected output**

```
 Date & Time                |     Waiting Time
2021-02-18 20:45:49.0000000 |   0Days15Hours0Mins
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting the `1 days` instead of `0 days`? The ultimate goal is to convert the date difference between the current timestamp and the date & time of the invoice into days hours and minutes format.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` counts the number of times a day changed to the next day. In your example the first day = 18 and the second day = 19, so `DATEDIFF` considers that a day difference. To get what you need you have to calculate the difference in hours(or minutes, seconds) and recalculate that to 24 hours

Comment: @HoneyBadger - thank you for your reply, managed to work it using the below coding:

`,convert(varchar(10),(DATEDIFF(s,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))/86400) + 'Days '
 + convert(varchar(10),((DATEDIFF(s,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))% 86400) /24) + 'Hours ' 
 + convert(varchar(10),(((DATEDIFF(s,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) % 86400) %3600)/60) + 'Mins' `

Comment: Seems a good solution. Feel free to answer your own question, it might help someone else in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the above using the below code:

```
convert(varchar(10),(DATEDIFF(s,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))/86400) + 'Days '  
+ convert(varchar(10),((DATEDIFF(s,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))% 86400) /24) + 'Hours '  
+ convert(varchar(10),(((DATEDIFF(s,[Date & Time],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) % 86400) %3600)/60) + 'Mins'
```